# How to handle __clone for child class object properties

Tags: php

When cloning an object that is a child of another object, is it "required" to indicate all the parent properties that are objects in the child class `__clone()` method or does the child class `__clone()` method can only include its own object properties that does not belong to the parent object?

Here is an example

The object `Child_A` extends the object `Parent_A`.

The object `Parent_A` uses the object `A_1` in its constructor and has a `__clone()` method.

```
class Parent_A{

   function __construct(A_1 $a_1){
      $this->A_1 = $a_1;
   }

   function __clone(){
      $this->A_1 = clone $this->A_1;
   }
}
```

The object `Child_A` requires `A_2` to construct.

```
class Child_A{

   function __construct(A_2 $a_2){
      parent::__construct(new A_1());

   }

   function __clone(){

      $this->A_2 = clone $this->A_2;
   }
}
```

If I want to make a deep copy of `Child_A` that would include a deep_copy `A_1`, should I use in `Child_A`:

```
   function __clone(){

      $this->A_1 = clone $this->A_1;
      $this->A_2 = clone $this->A_2;
   }
```

Or is the following enough as the parent object's clone method already includes `A_1`:

```
   function __clone(){

      $this->A_2 = clone $this->A_2;
   }
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this off the top of my head, but couldn't you inspect the created objects and determine this yourself?  My process for determining this would be to create an id for each object and have the object report it's id every step of the way either in an echo or an error_log.  Then, try both methods and see if you get the results you expect.

Comment: 100 bounty for already answered question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831798/php-deep-clone-object just use unserialize(serialize($object));

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, your `Child_A` does not extend `Parent_A`, so this construction

```
class Child_A {

    function __construct(A_2 $a_2){
        parent::__construct(new A_1());
    }
}
```

results with fatal error on the first attempt to instantiate the class.

Secondly, you make no use of `$a_2` there, so `Child_A::__clone` will result with notice of undefined variable `A_2`.

Finally, to answer the question - no, if not explicitly called, parent's `__clone` is not invoked. The recommended solution is to let the child handle clone of its own properties only, and let parent take care about its properties:

```
class Parent_A
{
    protected $a_1;

    function __construct(A_1 $a_1)
    {
        $this->a_1 = $a_1;
    }

    function __clone()
    {
        $this->a_1 = clone $this->a_1;
    }
}

class Child_A extends Parent_A
{
    protected $a_2;

    function __construct(A_2 $a_2)
    {
        $this->a_2 = $a_2;
        parent::__construct(new A_1);
    }

    function __clone()
    {
        $this->a_2 = clone $this->a_2;
        return parent::__clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for `parent::__clone()` this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that you need DeepCopy. Code taken from PHPExcel

```
public function __clone() {
    foreach($this as $key => $val) {
        if (is_object($val) || (is_array($val))) {
            $this->{$key} = unserialize(serialize($val));
        }
    }
}
```

There is also a module that will do this called [DeepCopy](https://github.com/myclabs/DeepCopy).

PHP Documentation has also defined [Objects Cloning](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php).

Comment: Be aware, it may not work if cloning logic is a bit more complex than just 'clone all properties'. Also un/serialisation invokes sleep magic, which may have side effects.