# PHP clone (deep copy)

Tags: php, clone, deep-copy, php-5.6

I want to create a deep copy of my object instead of a shallow one. If I simply call `clone` I receive an out of memory exception caused by circular references. How can I avoid circular references during my magic clone method?

```
public function __clone() {
    foreach($this as $key => $val) {
        if (is_object($val) || is_array($val) ) {
            $this->{$key} = unserialize(serialize($val));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure how to write this in PHP but I would, but one solution, I think, could be to store the references of already cloned objects in some kind or list/array and where you encounter one, use its clone reference as result.

Comment: you can use spl_object_hash to get hash of an object, store it and use it to skip already visited objects.

Comment: The 'only' way to get an exact copy, without running out of memory over circular references, is to remove all circular references before the copy, do the copy, and then recreate the circular references. Of course you have to do the latter in the copy, as well as in the original. Detailed knowledge of the objects involved is needed.

Comment: You may need to use `spl_object_hash()` to determin if you've "seen" an object before.

Comment: The `myclabs/deep-copy` library is excellent for this. A quick alternative is to run `$clone = unserialize(serialize($object));`, but it's not particularly pleasant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP deep clone object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831798/php-deep-clone-object)

Comment: @matt-s sadly not. Your referenced article is about deep copies in general but this question is about circular references and how to avoid them during magic cloen method

Comment: Just to add that be careful using `unserialize(serialize($object))` as it is very memory inefficient.