# Symfony - PHP - Deep cloning object

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, doctrine-orm, deep-copy

I have an object which is an instance of the entity class `Workflow`. This workflow has a property `$states` which is an instance of doctrines entity class `ArrayCollection`.

Part of my `Workflow` class:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

class Workflow  {

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Collection
     */
    private $states;

    /**
     * Workflow constructor.
     * @param ...t
     */
    public function __construct(...) {
        $this->states = new ArrayCollection();
        ...
    }

    /**
     * Get states
     *
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getStates() {
        return $this->states;
    }

    public function addState(State $state) {
        $state->setWorkflow($this);
        $this->states->add($state);

        return $this;
    }

    ...

}
```

`Workflow`s and `States`s are mapped and get stored into the database. Here parts are the `.orm.yml` mapping files:

`Workflow.orm.yml`:

```
MyBundle\Entity\Workflow:
  type: entity
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: {strategy: AUTO}
  oneToMany:
    states:
      targetEntity: MyBundle\Entity\State
      mappedBy: workflow
      cascade: [persist, remove]
      orphanRemoval: true
  ...
```

`State.orm.yml`:

```
MyBundle\Entity\State:
  type: entity
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: {strategy: AUTO}
  manyToOne:
    workflow:
      targetEntity: MyBundle\Entity\Workflow
      inversedBy: states
      cascade: [persist]
  ...
```

In know that I have a `Workflow` named *test* stored with a `State` named *release*. I have a route with object parameters using Symfonys [*ParamConverter*](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) with type hinting.

Here is a part of the `routing.yml`:

```
my_route:
    path: /project/{project}/editWorkflow/{workflow}
    defaults: { _controller: "MyBundle:Test:createEditWorkflowFirstPart", workflow: 0 }
```

Now I call the route with an existing *project* and an existing *workflow* e.g. `http://localhost/app_dev.php/de/testpra/project/79/editWorkflow/first/19` and expect Symfony to load the `workflow` in my action method.

#### My goal is to store the `loaded` workflow as a **deep clone** in my session and reload it in a second form part action method when the user submits an according button `WorkflowStatesType::NEXT_FORM_PART`.

---

### Now the problem

When calling the `createEditWorkflowFirstPartAction` via route the method indeed holds a `$workflow` object which is an instance of `Workflow` but when I dump all states via `dump($workflow->getStates()` there are no elements in the `ArrayCollection` but when running the states in a loop `foreach ($workflow->getStates() as $state) dump($state);` Symfony dumps the State of the Workflow stored in the database.

I never had such a strange behaviour of Symfony so I really don´t know if its the `dump` that does not *dump* right or if the `ArrayCollection` just loads the states when it thinks they are needed.

When now calling `unserialize(serialize($workflow));` to [**deep clone**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10831885/5233188) the `$workflow` the *unserialized* object does not dump any state when looping through states in a `foreach`.

Here is the `createEditWorkflowFirstPartAction` method:

```
public function createEditWorkflowFirstPartAction(Request $request, Project $project, Workflow $workflow = null) {

  $newWorkflow = false;

  if(!$workflow) {
    $workflow = new Workflow($project);
    $newWorkflow = true;
  }

  $workflowBeforeSubmit = unserialize(serialize($workflow));
  dump($workflow->getStates()); // Line 106 - Contains no elements
  dump($workflowBeforeSubmit->getStates()); // Line 107 - Contains no elements
  foreach ($workflow->getStates() as $state) dump($state); // Line 108 - Will print out my stored State
  foreach ($workflowBeforeSubmit->getStates() as $state) dump($state); // No states

  $firstFormPart = $this->createForm(WorkflowStatesType::class, $workflow);
  $firstFormPart->submit($request->get($firstFormPart->getName()), false);

  if($firstFormPart->isSubmitted() && $firstFormPart->isValid()) {
    ...
  }

  die();

  return $this->render('@MyBundle/Workflow/workflow_edit_create_first_part.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $firstFormPart->createView(),
  ));
}
```

And here is the according output (`PraWorkflow` = `Workflow`, `PraTestController` = `TestController`):

[image: Output]

---

1. Why are the `ArrayCollection`s empty and doesn´t hold the `State` (here id 26)?
2. Why do I get the State when using a foreach loop? Does `ArrayCollection` access the database?
3. Does `unserialize(serialize(...))` work to **deep clone** an object with all child objects? If not, how should I do it without having any reference to one of the objects part of the `$workflow` object?

Comment: Why you don't used the JMS serializer bundle, it really helps to print your collections by just calling $this->get('jms_serializer')->toArray($workflow->getStates()), of course after adding the required annotation, check the documentation: http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations

Comment: I know it's late but this can really help other people debug there lazy loading in doctrine. As you sad it's not populated, thats because you have set lazy load as @Mocrates pointed out but if you want to dump it (var_dump or dump) you can do what i do use iterator_to_array() and dump that or do i foreach which is longer.
example dump(iterator_to_array($workflow->getStates()))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every relation (whereas OnetoOne) are lazy loaded that's why doctrine don't populate your relation.

If you want it, Add an custom query in a repository and addSelect(alias.releationField) with a join part and your collection will be not empty.

You can also change a fetch mode in a entity by default to FETCH_EAGER

Comment: Adding `fetch: EAGER` to my `states` mapping in my `Workflow.orm.yml`mapping file worked like a charm.

Comment: @goulashsoup It depends of your collection but if you don't need to load it every time (in my example, I don't want addresses for each `find`), fetch mode LAZY is your friend ...

Answer (score 2):

Here's my implementation of deep cloning with collections :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="clients")
*/
class Client
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="client", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"}, orphanRemoval=true), fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     * @ORM\OrderBy("title"="ASC"})
     */
    protected $addresses;

    // ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->addresses = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...

    public function __clone()
    {
        if ($this->id)
        {
            $this->setId(null);
        }

        // cloning addresses
        $addressesClone = new ArrayCollection();
        foreach ($this->addresses as $address)
        {
            /* @var Address $address */
            $addressClone = clone $address;
            $addressClone->setClient($this);
            $addressesClone->add($addressClone);
        }
        $this->addresses = $addressesClone;
    }

    // ...

}
```

In controller, simply call `$copy = clone $client;` to get a perfect copy of your entity with collection.